# Should I use BehaviorSubject to create an Observable from a variable, if I only want the variable to emit itself when it changes?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

(First of all, although I think this is a question related to general `Rx` programming, but since I am developing `Android` and using `RxJava`, the below question will be asked in `Android` and `RxJava` context.)

I am new to `RxJava` and therefore want to implement it in some easy way first.

**Scenario**

I have a form, I want to enable the button only if all necessary fields in the form has been filled in.
I have already managed to implement this feature, for all `EditText` inputs.

Now, my form also has an image selection.
I therefore has a `Bitmap` variable which stores the image that user selected.
Since this image is also necessary, I need to enable the button only if this `Bitmap` variable is not `null`.

**Problem**

So, what I am thinking is, create an `Observable` from this `Bitmap` variable, that will emits itself (or at least a `Boolean`) when its value has been updated.

And then very quickly, I find some StackOverflow posts which suggest using `BehaviorSubject`.

The problem is, **in every starter tutorial of Rx I have read, `Subject` has not been mentioned**. And even on the official website of Rx, it has [a link](http://davesexton.com/blog/post/To-Use-Subject-Or-Not-To-Use-Subject.aspx) to an article where it said

> "[Subjects] are the "mutable variables" of the Rx world and in most
>   cases you do not need them."

So, I started to doubt whether I really should use Subject to do what I want. I suspect *may be I should create an Observable from the function which updates the variable*.

But then I am stuck. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This case is that rare case where `BehaviorSubject` is appropriate. You can `onNext` the image on it which will notify observers and you can `getValue()` to access this image directly afterwards.

Comment: That is glad to hear. Thanks!